# Sum of an infinite geometric series with squared powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that for $|r|<1$ the infinite geometric series has an explicit value as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n =\frac{1}{1-r}$$

Does there exist a similar result for

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{n^2}$$

I've seen some stuff on Jacobi-theta functions, but can't see how that applies to the non-complex number setting where $|r|<1$.

Comment: No, there is no elementary expression.

Comment: Is there an upper bound? Other than $\frac{1}{1-r}$?

Comment: Some estimates can be found here: [How to compute the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24662)

Comment: No, there is no similar form, and yes, Jacobi theta-functions are the way to go, regardless of the value of $r$.

Comment: Here's a paper on efficiently approximating theta functions: https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/thetalog.pdf

Comment: There may be some useful estimates/bounds in the paper, István Mező,
Several identities, estimates and special values for the elliptic theta functions,
Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Volume 527, Issue 2, 2023, 127515, ISSN 0022-247X, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2023.127515.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X23005188) but it's behind a paywall.

Comment: Also Korenkov M, Kharkevych Y. On the Asymptotics and Distribution of Values of the Jacobi Theta Functions and the Estimate of the Type of the Weierstrass Sigma Functions. Axioms. 2022; 11(1):12. https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms11010012 which is freely available looks like it might have some useful estimates.

Comment: Finding any of those links helpful, james?

Answer (score 1):

Will hazard a guess. Only an approximation though.

Let $\alpha=|\ln(|r|)|$.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ r^{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ e^{-\alpha n^2}$

Now I think you can bound the sum with modifications of the integral:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ e^{-\alpha n^2}\approx \int_0^\infty \ e^{-\alpha x^2} dx=\int_0^\infty \ (1-\alpha x^2+\frac{\alpha^2x^4}{2!}+...) dx$

No closed form solution for the partial sums.